# Printer prints a blank page after every first page

Tags: windows-8, drivers, printing, printer

I have new computer using Windows 8 and for some reason ever since I installed drivers for printers on it, it prints a blank page after the first page every time.

Like, the thing I wanted to print does get printed all right but there is this extra page and I have no idea why -.-

Also, when I wanted to print a two sided page, it printed on one side, then it took paper in to print on the other side but it printed a blank page and as if it broke the chain of printing on two sides, it didn't even take the paper inside for next pages.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this? Because it is pretty annoying, I even tried to reinstall drivers but it didn't help.

I think there might be a problem with settings or something but I am not sure where exactly to look nor what to look for :x

In case you guys needed to know, the printers are HP LJ 1320n and HP LJ 1160 and my computer is Asus T100TA and it runs Win 8.1.

Comment: Is this condition applies to all the document or specific to one?.

Comment: If the printer was being fed  data that the margins (say) were outside of the printable area for the printer itself, the printer could put the extra on a next page (even the blankness). Check the margins, check paper size, check the printer properties before printing, use "print previews" to view the layout that will be sent. Check also how many "pages" it claims it is about to print. check the 2up, and size to page , shrink to fit etc. Then check and fix the margins again :-)   Some printer drivers have thier OWN print preview, it can help. Add any information you learned to the question.

Comment: A Printers own print preview settings (if it exists) could be found in the advanced settings of the printer properties sheet. Its own print preview will show better what the printer driver (and software) sees going to it, vrses what the os or program is feeding it.